# How do I in Python from the start execute a list of script under def

Tags: python

Sorry I am considered quite new to Python but I still hope I can get help from here.

So I made a rock paper scissor game, and the script needs to be executed again after one round is over. The script looks something like this:

```
def introStuff():
  window.geometry("300x300")
  window.title("Rock Paper Scissor")
  welcomeMessage=Label(window, text="Welcome to Rock Paper Scissor!", font=("Arial Bold", 15))
  welcomeMessage.grid(column=0, row=0)
  welcomeButton=Button(window, text="Start game", bg="green", fg="white", command=startGame)
  welcomeButton.grid(column=0, row=3)
```

So I placed the script under `def introStuff()`. I know how to restart the script by using `command=introStuff` in a button that user clicks after one round, but the issue is that the script `introStuff` needs to execute upon launch to start a game of rock paper scissors, but I am unaware of any code that can accomplish that. Any suggestions?

Comment: where are you calling `introStuff()`?

Comment: at the very top of the script when the program is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where to call the function?

It depends how you launch your game. If there is some launch lifecycle hooks in whatever game framework you are using, then typically just calling your `introStuff` function in that framework launch sequence will work.

In other words, the framework you are using probably does some stuff when it is launched, and probably has provisioned ways to allow you to hook into this launch stage to run your own code. It is simply a matter of determining how the framework exposes this functionality, which depends on the framework.

#### How to call the function?

You can call the function, which will execute the code indented below it, by using the parentheses operators. Since the function definition does not specify any parameters, to call the function we need not supply any arguments, so the parentheses are empty:

`introStuff()`

Comment: I know this is supposed to be a very basic question but like I said, I am new to Python, but how do you call the `introStuff` function in the launch sequence, like what is the appropriate words you type in the first few line of the framework to accomplish that (I tried `exec(introStuff)` and it does not look like Python is recognizing it

Comment: I always use `goto introStuff` in Batch to do similar things for example

Comment: You can call a function with this syntax: `introStuff()`. Any parameters the function expects (in this case there are none) should be provided in the parantheses as such: `myFuncWithParams(10, "foo", 36.25)`

Comment: Thank you mate that is the precise answer I needed! :D